# Blackbox Exporter endpoints with FQDN

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

i was wonder myself how to get in Prometheus UI under the Blackbox-Exporter section the endpoints with their FQDN. Let's say i want to probe https://www.google.de but i only get http://localhost:9115/probe, here is my example configuration:

```
- job_name: blackbox-exporter
  metrics_path: /probe
  static_configs:
    - targets: ["https://www.google.de/"]
      labels:
        module: https_get
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels:
        - __address__
      target_label: __param_target
    - source_labels:
        - __param_target
      target_label: instance
    - source_labels:
        - module
      target_label: __param_module
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: localhost:9115
```

Here the output in Prometheus UI:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7BqR.png)

Is there a way to get https://www.google.de instead of http://localhost:9115/probe. I would appreciate any suggestion. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get what you want at the following URL:

```
https://BLACKBOX-SERVER/probe?target=https://www.google.de
```

Comment: What did you mean by that? That I should use google to find the answer? How did I not come up with such a brilliant idea? If you have nothing constructive to add, please do not waste my time. Thank you in any case for your response, even if it was not helpful.

Comment: No!!! It's not a joke. I'm not saying to you to search on Google or anything like that (why did you think that?). I don't know if I understand correctly your question, but I'm saying that you can get all Blackbox metrics of some target if you point your browser to the "probe?target=TARGET" path on the Blackbox server. Try it and you'll see.

Comment: Hello Marcelo, sorry if i got you wrong. Back to the question. Your suggestion is right but i guess i've formulated the question incorrectly. What i wanted to know was, if i can change directly under ```https://fqdn-prometheus/*/targets?search=``` the endpoint name from localhost to Target FQDN. If i use the node_exporter for example, i always get ```https://ns-blue.com/9100/metrics``` as endpoint name. I'd like to get in the blackbox section a similar output, something like ```https://www.google.com``` when i probe https://www.google.com and not localhost:9115. Do you understand what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

the solution for this problem (not to see http(s)://localhost:9115 as blackbox) was to create the right entry in the DNS Server (CNAME)

```
my-prometheus.com  A       IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
my-blackbox.com    CNAME   my-prometheus
```

and create another vhost in apache pointing to the new created CNAME. We make all this with Puppet so here is the code for that:

```
prometheus::server::scrape_configs:
  - job_name: prometheus
    scheme: https
    metrics_path: /prom/metrics
    static_configs:
    - targets:
        - 'my-prometheus.com'

 - job_name: blackbox-exporter
   scheme: https
   metrics_path: /blackbox/metrics
   static_configs:
    - tartgets:
        - https://www.google.de/

   relabel_configs:
     - source_labels:
         - __address__
       target_label: __param_target
     - source_labels:
         - __param_target
       target_label: instance
     - source_labels:
         - module
       target_label: __param_module
     - target_label: __address__
       replacement: "my-blackbox.com"

profile::apache::vhosts:
  blackbox_exporter:
    servername: "my-blackbox.com"
    docroot: /var/www
    port: 443
    ssl: true
    ssl_cert: /path/to/cert.pem
    ssl_key: /path/to/-key.pem
    ssl_chain: /path/to/chain.pem
    directories:
      - path: /blackbox/
        provider: location
        proxy_pass:
          - url: http://localhost:9115/
        require:
          enforce: any
```

So you get https://my-blackbox.com/blackbox/metrics in prometheus UI. When we click on that link, we get all the metrics of the targets. You can check this in the URL: https://my-blackbox.com/metrics?module=https_get_ok&target=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.de%2F

I hope this can help someone else. Thanks to Marcelo for his help.